# Creating a maximum value allowed trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger which does a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION as soon as a certain value is reached in a table.

Imagine that a Student of a uni library is only able to have 5 active loans simultaneously. How would I implement that kind of trigger?

This is what we have so far:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `bib_db`.`Customer_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `Customer` FOR EACH ROW 

if activeloans <5
AND Customertype = student
then

  SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "You've reached your maximum ammount of loans";
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
end if ; 
end
```

I might be way off, but this is as far as i've got...Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two important things.  First, you should use a `before` update trigger to prevent the update from happening.  Second, the logic is backwards.  Something more like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER bib_db.Customer_BEFORE_UPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Customer`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    if activeloans >= 5 AND Customertype = 'student' then
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "You've reached your maximum ammount of loans";
    end if ; 
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

end

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! Unfortunately i'm still able to performe the update in the table customer without any error message showing up. I'm Currently using heidiSQL although I dont see that being the problem...anything else I've might forgot?

Comment: **I actually did get it to work now although I cant seem to get the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION to work. 
The trigger that worked = 


BEGIN
    if new.AktivaLan >5 AND new.Kundtyp= 'Student' then
        SIGNAL sqlstate '20001' set message_text = "You've reached your maximum ammount of loans";
  end if ; 
    
END

Tried to add a ROLLBACK syntax but I get an error message saying:
SQL Error (1422): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.